# Android trying to get the RadioGroup object so I can hide it

Tags: java, android

Trying to get a reference to a radio group defined in the xml file.
Usually I use `findViewById(R.id.idAll);` to get a reference to a ui object. Cant figure out how to do it for a `RadioGroup`.

Answer (score 0):

Radio group is the same as any view. You can use

```
 RadioGroup rg = findViewById(R.id.idAll);
```

Comment: i COULD NOT GET THAT TO WORK i GOT A ERROR SAYING

Comment: UNEXPECTED CAST TO llinarlayout

Comment: Try with  RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.idAll); and make sure R.id.idAll is the id of radio group.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);

        rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // Method 1 For Getting Index of RadioButton
            pos=rg.indexOfChild(findViewById(checkedId));

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Method 1 ID = "+String.valueOf(pos),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //Method 2 For Getting Index of RadioButton
            pos1=rg.indexOfChild(findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Method 2 ID = "+String.valueOf(pos1),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                switch (pos)
                {
                case 0 :
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have Clicked RadioButton 1",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 1 :
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have Clicked RadioButton 2",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 2 :
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have Clicked RadioButton 3",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            default :
                //The default selection is RadioButton 1
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"You have Clicked RadioButton 1" ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                }
        }
    });
```